# Dynamically created html elements are rendered as text

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div and I want to create radio-button list dynamically using javascript. This code renders text for some reason, not html radio buttons and labels:

```
    var a1 = document.getElementById("my_div");
    for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
      a1.append("<label><input type=\"radio\" name=\"rbtn\" value=\"" + result.data.[i].id + "\" />" + result.data[i].name + "</label>");
    }
```

Why is it rendered as text?

Comment: [`Element.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Comment: Instead of adding a "never mind..." comment as "answer" either delete the question or add your solution and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Andreas, I don't want to

Answer (score 2):

change this:

```
a1.append("<label><input type=\"radio\" name=\"rbtn\" value=\"" + result.data.[i].id + "\" />" + result.data[i].name + "</label>");
```

to

```
a1.innerHTML+="<label><input type=\"radio\" name=\"rbtn\" value=\"" + result.data.[i].id + "\" />" + result.data[i].name + "</label>";
```

about [apend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append)

> The ParentNode.append method inserts a set of Node objects or
>   DOMString objects after the last child of the ParentNode. **DOMString objects are inserted as equivalent Text nodes.**